# How to use custom phonegap 3.3 plugin in iOS

Tags: ios, plugins, cordova

I already use phonegap plugin (SQLitePlugin) in phonegap 2.9, but now i want to convert my project to phonegap 3.3,
i already follow the instruction, but i'm having problem when calling the plugin from javascript. it always says :  undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase');

Please help, Thanks.

EDITED :  i already make it working, which is to copy the SQLitePlugin.js to www folder and write the script tag in the index.html,

But i'm curious because based on this article it said that we don't have to copy the js file and no need to write the script tags.

EDITED : the Correct Solution is, after adding the plugin using plugin add command, you must rebuild your project again using phonegap build ios command.

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/9/6/Working-with-Plugins-in-PhoneGap-30

> My assumption at this point was to copy all the JS files into my www folder and add script  tags to my index.html.
>
> That is not necessary!
>
> In 3.0 (see footnotes), the build process not only handles copying the Java file over, it > copies the JavaScript and injects it into your HTML. Basically, I don't have to do
> anything special on the HTML side to make use of my plugin. That kicks ass! But I wish I
> had known that earlier. You can literally just start using the plugin after deviceready has fired:

Comment: Hoy remember add your <feature> tag with the plugin definition in the config.xml?

Comment: post ur code also may have issues

Comment: window.SQLitePlugin.openDatabase instead of window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase

Comment: in version 3.x, the <feature> tag is automatically added when we used the plugin add command.

Comment: what happen why uncheck my answer

Comment: i already checked again, but actually the issue is still open "do i must copy the js file and write the script tags in the index.html" or i don't have to ??, but currently if i don't copy the js file, i cannot call the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do I have to change in my existing applications?
Not much.

Just replace "**window.openDatabase**" with "**window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase**".

Don't forget to take a look at the limitations of Windows Phone Plugin.

**How to install the SQLite Plugin**

There are so many SQL Plugins available. I choose "lite4cordova", because it supports Cordova 3.x, it is easy to install and it is still in development.

https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin-WP-2013.12

The second project is an extension of "Cordova-SQLitePlugin", because Windows Phone is not working on "Cordova-SQLitePlugin" yet.

[image]

this link helpful more http://tol8.blogspot.in/

or

checkout your Opening a database options

There are two options to open a database:

```
Recommended: var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "DB"});
Classical: var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Demo", -1);
```

[more details](https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin-2013.09)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add your plugin KEY/VALUE pair in the Cordova.plist under the dictionary PLUGINS, this way your ios Code will know which class you are referring to!